# Why is my query not returning an array of Enums

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, prisma

I am having some issues with querying an array of Enums in a GraphQL query. I am expecting that the array or permissions will be returned with the user as per the type

Bizarrely, when I make the same query in the playground (for either my Prisma or Apollo-Server servers) I do get back the array.

My query looks like this:

```
const user = await ctx.db.query.user({
  where: {
    id: ctx.userId
  }
});
```

My type definition looks like this:

```
type User {
    id: ID! @id
    name: String!
    email: String! @unique
    password: String!
    club: String!
    permissions: [Permission!]! @scalarList(strategy: RELATION)
    createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
    updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
}
```

permissions looking like

```
enum Permission {
    ADMIN
    CLUB_ADMIN
    USER
    FRIEND
}
```

I haven’t included my query resolver as I have just forwarded that to the DB using “forward-to”

But the CL of user is

```
{ id: 'cjxm9ohfqvkvh0b5963iy734i',
  name: 'BERTIE BOBBINS',
  email: 'BERTIE@DOGS.COM',
  password: '$2b$10$eLPoBuuenogLabiFb4tRFu0KV7LI4LxARhHecPYVbP0qnt5VvcZ3W',
  club: 'Dog Club',
  createdAt: '2019-07-02T20:30:49.670Z',
  updatedAt: '2019-07-02T20:30:49.670Z' }
```

So not including the Permissions array.

Comment: If it works in playground it works, so it must be your client-side query that is the issue. Why does a user have an array of permissions? Wouldn't one user have one permission type?

Comment: Each permission relates to a different set of permissions, could be a user and also a club_admin, admin, etc. I haven’t got onto the client side query yet. This is just querying the prisma db and Apollo server db and the query is directly taken from the generated schema. I think that when a record is created with an array of enums you have toy use a “set”, do I need to explicitly “get” the contents of the array and if so, how, and how come the playground works?

Comment: Ran into this same issue. I haven't found a fix for it, but if you want the permissions field to be returned, you need to pass it in as a return field, and also pass in the `info` object as the second argument to the `ctx.db.query.user` function

Answer (score 0):

[Introspection](https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/) system this introspection types

1. __Schema
2. __Type
3. __TypeKind
4. __Field
5. __InputValue
6. __EnumValue
7. __Directive

To query the enums you need to use the __Type query resolver.

```
enum Permission {
    ADMIN
    CLUB_ADMIN
    USER
    FRIEND
}
```

query for enum

```
query 
{
 __type(name: "Permission") {
   name
   enumValues {
     name
   }
 }
}
```

The __type query resolver requires the name parameter. This parameter allows you to search your schema for items such as objects and enums based on their name.

```
{
 "data": {
   "__type": {
   "name": "Permission", 
   "enumValues" : [
     {
       name: "ADMIN" 
     },
     { 
       name: "CLUB_ADMIN" 
     },
     { 
       name: "USER" 
     },
     { 
       name: "FRIEND"
     }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

This returns the name of the enum with all of its values.
To use these values, store them in a variable when querying the enums.

```
PermissionsList = data.__type.enumValues
```

If you need enum inside user object [ref this](https://graphqlmastery.com/blog/how-to-use-graphql-enum-type-and-its-best-practices)

If you use apollo server then read [apollo-server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/scalars-enums/) and [graphql-tools](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars/#internal-values)

Comment: Is this to get the array of permissions for a specific user or to introspect what the possible values of the enum are?

Comment: For now, you can return enum. If you need to permissions for a specific user you can return an array. Please check your Query resolver  and return [array of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018992/how-to-iterate-json-nested-array-in-graphql-scheme/55019511#55019511).

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand: you mention you simply used the `prisma-binding` `forwardTo` function, but then provide your sample query where you forward to the `db` from the context using `ctx.db.query.user`. Did you have the issue in both cases?

For the `forwardTo` instance, I do not know the answer. But for the second case, I also had this issue, and was able to resolve it by passing in the `info` object from the resolver function signature as the second argument to the query.

```
const user = await ctx.db.query.user(
  {
    where: {
      id: ctx.request.userId
    }
  },
  info
);
```